# Styling angular 2 tooltips

Tags: angular, angular2-template

this is an li which has tooltips on it and i want to style these
as they are on angular 2 mat tooltip i am unable to do it

```
<li
      routerLinkActive="active"
      routerLink="/dashboard"
      matTooltip="TEst"
      matTooltipPosition="after">
      <span class="icon-dashboard"></span>
    </li>
```

i am unable to style this

i have tried using

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    color: yellow;
}
```

but it is still not working please help

Comment: You can make use of `matTooltipClass` property to customize your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Add !important after yellow, bye

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip  {
       color:yellow!important; // for example 
}
```